# Problem running Google Chrome in Kali Linux

Tags: chrome, kali-linux

I want to run google-chrome in Kali Linux. But I am facing some problem. I have installed google chrome by following the steps mentioned [here](http://www.blackmoreops.com/2013/12/01/install-google-chrome-kali-linux-part-2/). It is successfully installed with chrome being displayed on

```
Application -> Internet -> Google Chrome
```

To run google chrome I followed [Part 3](http://www.blackmoreops.com/2013/12/01/install-google-chrome-kali-linux-part-3/) of the same series. There are three different ways listed on how we can run chrome. 
One option is it says to edit the file using leafpad `leafpad /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome` find the lines 
`exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@"` and append it with **-user-data-dir**. But the same file is a bit different in my computer, it looks something like this.

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$PROFILE_DIRECTORY_FLAG" \
"$@"
```

But even though I tried to add **-user-data-dir** to the end which now looks like

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$PROFILE_DIRECTORY_FLAG" \
"$@"-user-data-dir.
```

But it is not working anyway.

Then i tried another option. It says that first we have to create a user using
`useradd -m chromeuser`  and then type `gksu -u chromeuser google-chrome` to run chrome. However I am getting the following error after running the last command. It says

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss3.so: version `NSS_3.14.3' not found (required by /usr/bin/google-chrome)
```

How can I install chrome successfully?

Comment: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/google-chrome-error-loading-libnss3-so-811621/

Comment: I downloaded mozilla-nss from SlackBuilds. I have unzipped the tar file. Then changing the path to mozilla-nss(extracted folder) i am doing this        

`root@kali:/Sanchit/mozilla-nss# sudo ./mozilla-nss.SlackBuild 

tar: /Sanchit/mozilla-nss/nss-3.12.4-with-nspr-4.8.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory

tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
`

Comment: can you please tell me what i doing wrong ?

Comment: run this command: apt-get -f install

Answer (score 8):

Now you cannot run google-chrome as root user on updated versions, To run Google Chrome as standard user (while Logged in as Root)

Open terminal and type:

```
useradd -m chromeuser
```

or

```
adduser -u chromeuser
```

To run google chrome use command:

```
gksu -u chromeuser google-chrome
```

or

```
sux chromeuser google-chrome
```

If you don't want to run it from Terminal then add chrome in taskbar and then
right-click on it, select properties and add the above command in the command parameter.

Comment: This is the proper answer and issue.

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Debian, and with Chrome's last 2 updates, the sandbox seems to have began acting up, so I tried searching online if anyone have encountered it (though it may be also because of other software I have installed).

Replacing the last bits of lines with:

```
exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --user-data-dir
```

seemed to work for me before (prior to chrome's last 2 updates).

Now though, what seems to work is:

1. Running chrome as non-root user, set the launcher property to:

   ```
   gksu -u nonRootUser /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
   ```
2. Running chrome as root user, set it to:

   ```
   /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --no-sandbox --user-data-dir &
   ```

Comment: Actually, this seems like a better approach because you are not creating a new user just to make chrome work, but are rather assigning chrome to an existing user ...

Comment: I add to add `sudo` to solution `1`: `sudo gksu -u nonRootUser /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`

Answer (score 2):

Removing the period at the end of `-user-data-dir.` should do the trick.

Also, the error message displayed specifies 02 dashes.  Either one seems to work for me at the moment, but you may want to play it safe in case Google decides to force one way over the other.  So `--user-data-dir` seems to be more proper.

Answer (score 1):

You can run chrome as root by `un-sandboxing` it.

Navigate to `/usr/share/applications` and change the lines below:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --incognito
```

To

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --no-sandbox
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --no-sandbox
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --incognito --no-sandbox
```

> You can temporarily run this in terminal by typing `google-chrome --no-sandbox`

I made a simple script that can help enable or disable different browsers in root. The script will present you a menu which will enable or disable a browser based on your selection.

[**Github repo link**](https://github.com/david-kariuki/linux-unsandbox-browsers-cli)

[Profile link](https://github.com/david-kariuki/)

Use the profile link incase the repo link wount work.