# Google Chrome in Kali Linux 2016

Tags: kali-linux

How can I install **Google Chrome** in **Kali Linux 2016**?

Comment: If you really don't know the answer to this, one does have to wonder why you're using Kali and not a friendlier distribution.

Comment: Also see [Problem running Google Chrome in Kali Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154719/problem-running-google-chrome-in-kali-linux)

Answer (score 10):

Kali Linux 2.0 is based on Debian Jessie.

1. Go to [Google Chrome for Linux](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/) page.
2. Click on the `Download Chrome` button at the bottom, accept license agreement, download `google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`.
3. Install prerequisites using (assuming you are logged on as `root`):

   ```
   apt-get install -f
   ```
4. Install Google Chrome:

   ```
   dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
   ```
5. To run Google Chrome have a look at the answers to this question: [Problem running Google Chrome in Kali Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154719/problem-running-google-chrome-in-kali-linux)

Comment: I recieve `Illegal instruction` after installing as you describe and launching `google-chrome`. Please help.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but `apt-get install -f` didn't fix my issue. First of all, I had to use `sudo` for all commands and I had to install extra package as`libappindicator1` by doing `sudo apt-get install libappindicator1` but had to fix my broken installation for some reason doing  `sudo apt --fix-broken install`. So now it is working great.

Answer (score 0):

You should first run

```
$ dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Then if you run into errors, try using `apt-get install -f`. Correct instructions - just the wrong way around.